# How can I see what are the GET requests and POST responses and "print" commands with apache xampp?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

i recently began developing php with xampp and apache on windows 7. I'm used to have a shell open with all the server transactions when developing with other environments. I'm working a lot with ajax and i love this "print" commands...

How can I see the GET requests, the POST responses and the contents of "print" with xampp? Probably there is a DOS command to start the apache and see it working...but how is that going?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Firefox extensions, you should try [liveHttpHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) or [tamper data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) (the latest have more filters)

For a more in depth way, see [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

**Edit:**
For the `print()` part, I recommend you to install **firebug** and **firePHP** addons for Firefox.

Comment: thanks a lot...i heard of it...uaah i got it and installed it...how can i make wireshark to sniff at the local port?

Comment: By filtering on your local IP (if you have one) like 192.168.x.x or 10.0.x.x or 172.16.x.x

Comment: firePHP really is great...thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Look into the access.log of the apache server in xampp
2. Install a extension like firebug for firefox and use the network module. Which displays the information in more detail and nicer formatted see picture
3. You could install wireshark like sputnick said, but that would be overkill though

I hope its what you meant. I'm not sure about the "print" though.

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering this is what I do at the moment...but this is not really making me happier...i miss the print results so much...;-)

Comment: then i dont get what you mean by print results. could you elaborate?

Comment: thanks for helping: I meant a print command with some variables in it like "print($test)". when i have a php script which is called from a ajax command this print command normally shows up in the server log...which is not happening with xampp...